# Remove required field in validation form

Tags: 8, forms

If I have a multiple field (ajax) required: FIELD_A (N), and I want it not required if: FIELD_B has a certain value. How can I do ? Any function in $ form_state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use states to style the input as required. This won't actually perform any validation but will add the required asterisk to the field when field B has a certain value.

```
$form['FIELD_A']['#states'] = [
  'required' => array(
    ':input[name="FIELD_B"]' => array('value' => 'foo'),
  ),
];
```

Then use custom [validation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/introduction-to-form-api#fapi-validation) to actually check FIELD_A has the correct value depending on the value of FIELD_B.

Comment: ! Ok thz. It did not work due to a bug on a contrib field, then ok.